# How to change the app theme if I have more than 2 themes

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

I am studying flutter and I have a problem how to make a switch between themes if flutter seems to have only dark and light (as I think). I have a switch between light and dark theme. There are also 4 buttons where you can change the secondary color of the application.
[How it looks in the app:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91OlG.png)
Themes code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Themes {
  static final ThemeData light = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.green,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
      background: Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 240, 240),
      onBackground: Colors.white,
      shadow: Color.fromARGB(255, 200, 200, 200),
      secondary: Colors.black,
      surface: Color.fromARGB(245, 255, 255, 255),
      primaryContainer: Color.fromARGB(245, 230, 230, 230),
    ),
  );

  static final ThemeData dark = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.green,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
      onBackground: Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 30, 30),
      background: Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 45, 45),
      shadow: Color.fromARGB(255, 144, 144, 144),
      secondary: Colors.white,
      surface: Color.fromARGB(245, 20, 20, 20),
      primaryContainer: Color.fromARGB(245, 30, 30, 30),
    ),
  );
}
```

Theme manager code:

```
import 'package:Zuba/theme/theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

class ThemeManager {
  final _box = GetStorage();
  final _keyBright = 'isDarkMode';
  final _keyColor = 'isColorMode';

  bool loadThemeFromBox()=>_box.read(_keyBright)??false;
  int loadThemeColorFromBox()=>_box.read(_keyColor)??0;
  ThemeMode get theme => loadThemeFromBox()?ThemeMode.dark:ThemeMode.light;
  _saveThemeToBox(bool isDarkMode) => _box.write(_keyBright, isDarkMode);
  _saveThemeColorBox(int isColorMode) => _box.write(_keyColor, isColorMode);
  void changeTheme(int color, bool mode) {
    _saveThemeToBox(mode);
    _saveThemeColorBox(color);
    if (mode) {
      switch (color) {
        case 0:
          Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
          break;
        case 1:
          Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
          break;
        case 2:
          Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
          break;
        case 3:
          Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
          break;
      }
    } else {
      switch (color) {
        case 0:
          Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.light);
          break;
        case 1:
          Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.light);
          break;
        case 2:
          Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.light);
          break;
        case 3:
          Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.light);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Button:

```
SizedBox(
    height: 35,
    width: 35,
    child: ElevatedButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero),
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
        RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
        ThemeManager().changeTheme(0, isDark);
        setState(() {
            isColor = 0;
            });
        },
        child: Icon(
            Icons.check,
            size: 22,
            color: (isColor == 0)
                ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
                : const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
        ),
    ),
),
```

If there are knowledgeable people, answer how best to write the current code)

I have an idea to change either only the primary color, or to change the entire ThemeData. Only I do not know how it can be implemented, but I have not found anything like this on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can have as many themes in your app as you like.

The `MaterialApp` widget that sits at or very close to the top of the widget tree in a lot of apps has got a `theme` property.

I think the easiest way to change the theme of your app is to make your app a `Stateful` widget with a build method that returns a `MaterialApp` widget. Then when the user selects a new theme by tapping a button, rebuild your `MaterialApp` widget with the updated `ThemeData` value for the `MaterialApp` widget's `theme` property using `setState`.

Here is a simple app to demonstrate this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ThemeChanger());
}

class ThemeChanger extends StatefulWidget {
  const ThemeChanger({super.key});

  @override
  State<ThemeChanger> createState() => _ThemeChangerState();
}

class _ThemeChangerState extends State<ThemeChanger> {
  final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.green,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
      background: Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 240, 240),
      onBackground: Colors.white,
      shadow: Color.fromARGB(255, 200, 200, 200),
      secondary: Colors.black,
      surface: Color.fromARGB(245, 255, 255, 255),
      primaryContainer: Color.fromARGB(245, 230, 230, 230),
    ),
  );

  final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.green,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
      onBackground: Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 30, 30),
      background: Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 45, 45),
      shadow: Color.fromARGB(255, 144, 144, 144),
      secondary: Colors.white,
      surface: Color.fromARGB(245, 20, 20, 20),
      primaryContainer: Color.fromARGB(245, 30, 30, 30),
    ),
  );

  final thirdTheme = ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red);

  late ThemeData currentTheme = lightTheme;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: currentTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  currentTheme = lightTheme;
                }),
                child: const Text('Light theme'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  currentTheme = darkTheme;
                }),
                child: const Text('Dark theme'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  currentTheme = thirdTheme;
                }),
                child: const Text('Third theme'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```